# Index not being used on new rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, statistics, sql-execution-plan

SQL Server 2008. We have a 1 TB database table (has a blob field with image data) over which there is an index on `date` and `account number`.

We insert around 30k rows per day. The index will be used in the query plan properly when searching on dates that EXISTED PRIOR TO creating the index (or rebuilding it). However searching on new rows (rows added since the index was built), it only uses the PK Clustered index.

I'm new at this, but I shouldn't have to rebuild the index daily should I? Statistics don't seem to be updated in the past few days (since I rebuild the index) but they are set to auto-update.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ProcessDate_Account] ON [dbo].[tablename] 
(
    [Date] DESC,
    [Account] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have to rebuild daily.

SQL may trigger an update on the statistics to occur but continue to use old statistics in the meantime because updating takes a while.  Especially on a VLDB.  So Auto-Update is likely doing it's job but because of lack of resources or the time it's taking to get better information the optimizer isn't able to take advantage of it yet.

Run this to see when the last time Auto-Update was triggered

```
DBCC show_statistics ('<yer table>', '<yer index>') WITH STAT_HEADER
```

If your table only gets it's updates in batches.  (you mention 30k rows in a day; are those all at once??).  Microsoft recommends that instead of using Auto-Update in the scenario where you insert a large number of rows in a single batch **and then little to no rows after** to instead run [Update Stats with full scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).  (note: this still takes awhile to complete)